# Not sure what's wrong. Lots of strings embedded ruby and math

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= link_to "Next week", "/?week_forward= %>
<% if week_number % 52 == 0 %> 
    2 
<% else %> 
    1
<% end %>
<%= + #{(params[:week_forward].to_i || 0)}" %>
```

I am trying to get this in my html.erb.  I'm really not sure what is wrong, are my quotation marks wrong?

Here is the error

```
bad URI `/?week_forward=%20);@output_buffer.safe_concat('');%20if%20week_number%20%%2052%20==%200%20%20@output_buffer.safe_concat(''2'');%20else%20%20@output_buffer.safe_concat(''1'');%20end%20@output_buffer.append=%20(%20+%200'.
```

Comment: You'll make your life a lot easier if you wrap this in a helper

Comment: In a helper file: `def week_helper(week_number); week_number % 52 == 0 ? 2 : 1; end`
In the views: `<% link_params = "/?week_forward=#{ week_helper(12)}" %>`, `<%= link_to "Next week", link_params %>`

Something along that lines could do, but it's not anywhere near clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using `link_to` properly; the week number `1` or `2` needs to be part of the 2nd argument, not appended after the call to `link_to`.

```
<%= link_to "Next week", "/?week_forward=%d" % (week_number % 52 == 0) ? 2 : 1 %>
```

Your `link_to` is going to create the following *(once you fix the close quote after `"/?week_forward=`)*

```
<a href="/?week_forward=">Next Week</a>1
```

when you appear to want something like

```
<a href="/?week_forward=1">Next Week</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious error that jumps out is the missing double-quote after: `"/?week_forward=`

Also, you should definitely look up `helpers` in Rails, and move most of this code out of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Use following which looks very pretty

```
<% forward = params[:week_forward].to_i || 0 
   week_forward = week_number % 52 == 0 ? 2 : 1
%>
<%= link_to "Next week", "/?week_forward=#{week_forward+forward}" %>
```